# Uniqueness of geometric simplicial structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, simplicial-stuff

By work of Stallings we know that $\mathbb{R}^n$ (for $n\neq4$) has unique simplicial structure up to equivalence. If instead of a general simplicial structure we consider only geometric simplicial structures ie each simplex is convex hull of $n+1$ geometrically independent point in $\mathbb{R}^N$, then can we say that any such two geometric simplicial structures of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n\neq 4$) are equivalent?
In this case we are considering the category of geometric simplicial structures, so the subdivisions should be also geometric simplicial structures. I do not know whether in the proof of Stallings there is any restriction on the subdivisions or we can take them geometric simplicial structures if needed.

Comment: Unimportant correction: one should say "PL structure". Your triangulations are such that the link of every vertex is a sphere. There are inequivalent non-PL triangulations of $S^5$ by the double suspension theorem.

Comment: As for your question, I'm a little confused. If Stallings tells you that every two (PL) triangulations are equivalent, this in particular includes the class of (PL) geometric triangulations, in your sense. Is the notion of "equivalence" different between the two statements?

Comment: I suppose that equivalence now means "a sequence of geometric bisteller moves".  So the intermediate simplicial structures are also geometric.

Comment: @SamNead here two geometric simplicial structures are equivalent means they have two subdivisions which are again geometric simplicial structures and are isomorphic by a simplicial map. If any two geometric simplicial structures of Rn
 (n≠4
) are equivalent, can you give the sketch of the proof or a reference?

Comment: @mme,  in this case we are considering the category of geometric simplicial structures, so the subdivisions should be also geometric simplicial structures. I do not know whether in the proof of Stallings there is any restriction on the subdivisions or we can take them geometric simplicial structures if needed.